# Translation of "CD" and "DVD"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, abreviaturas

What are the possibilities for translating "CD" (Compact Disc) and "DVD" (Digital Video/Versatile Disc) into Spanish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CD and DVD safely. In some countries they are pronunced as in spanish (cedé, devedé) and in others like in english (cidí, dividí). The translations are:

1. **CD (Compact disc)**: Disco compacto.
2. **VCD (Video CD)**: Disco compacto de video
3. **DVD (Digital video/versatile disc)**: Disco Versátil Digital, Disco de Video Digital.
4. **CD-RW**: CD regrabable.
5. **DVD±RW**: DVD regrabable.

Comment: But for the regular use, I guess all cases are covered.

Comment: As a funny note, RAE accepts [*cederrón*](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=cederrón) for CD-ROM

Comment: That could be an example about when people shouldn't follow RAE recomendations :)

Comment: Aha, so not "deuvedé"?

Answer (score 5):

Both are well known (in most countries) as:

> Disco compacto

Here in Perú, we don't use `Disco compacto` at all. We use their abbreviated names: `CD` and `DVD` (with English pronunciation)

Answer (score 1):

No translation, only to CD is

> Disco Compacto

and DVD is:

> Disco Compacto de Video

Comment: DVD isn't "Disco compacto de Video".